# Using a cell content as an arg of an address in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list going from 1 to 10000 in column A. `(A1 has 1, A2 has 2, etc...)`
I have a function in column D that takes the number in column A and does a bit of math. This is simple. In fact, it can be reduced to increment an even number by 1 from the previous even number`(2=1, 4=2, 6=3, etc...)`, and add 6 to the prior odd number after 3 (which is set at 10).

Now, to the meat of the question.

I need a function for column B that uses the value in column D and adds 1.

For this example, `D2=1, D3=10, D4=2, D5=16,` etc...`

so `B2=B1+1, B3=B10+1, B4=B2+1, B5=B16+1,` etc...`

So, who knows how to do this?

Comment: For the example, when I say b3=b10+1, I do not mean b3=b11. b10 in this example is 6, so the number in b3 should be 7

Comment: `=INDIRECT("B" & D2) + 1`

Comment: `=OFFSET(B$1,D2-1,0) + 1`

Comment: I used the first one, and I was able to drag it down and autochange d2 to d3 on line 3, etc. Thank you!